# Table's width frozen because of display: block

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

I created a page containing a `table` and some data in it. Although I set table's width to 80% of it's parent div, the inner `tbody` and other children's width is frozen to 450px.

I also noticed that once I removed the property `display: block`, the table's children were correctly displayed (100% width of the table)

I there a particular reason for width to be frozen at 450px ? I checked everywhere in my CSS, and I did not set such a rule.

Here is the code of my table :

```
<div id="maincol">
<table width="80%" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" id="dates" class="summary" name="dates" style="display:block">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
                 ...
```

Comment: Why are you using `display: block` in the first place?

Comment: Sorry I just took example from a website to build my layout =s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tables have their own display type: "**table**" (and it's the only one possible), similarly **tr** and **td** have respectively display "**table-row**" and "**table-cell**"

Comment: so the 450px width is a default value generated by the browser from display's discrepancy ?

Comment: the 450px can be the result of several factors: what is the width of "#maincol"? (theoretically the 450px should be the rounded width of 80% of parent's width... is your container's width 562px?) what is the default style applied to tables in your css? What about "#dates" and ".summary"...

Comment: the div #maincol has 80% width of parent's div which width is set to 100% (1139px for my resolution)

Comment: so... by considering only nodes width, the table should be sized to 728/729px (1139 * 0.8 * 0.8). This is strange indeed... it may be a combination of paddings and margins, but it's hard to say :P